# ActiveX control works in HTML, but not (quite) in ASPX. What's the difference?

Tags: asp.net, html, activex

I’m trying to use a third-party ActiveX control on our intranet ASP.NET site, and I’ve run into a problem I can’t figure out.

Expected behavior:  The control expects to see a specific variable in the URL (“msg”).  If you provide it, it works.  If you don’t provide it, it complains that the value is missing.

If I put the control in an HTML page, it works fine.  But if I then change the page’s type to aspx, the control acts as if the variable isn’t there.  The control still loads and runs; I’m not getting any permission or safety messages.  But it complains that “msg” wasn’t provided on the URL.

In other words, if I try these URLs, the first one works fine; the second one gives me the "you didn't provide the msg parameter" complaint:

(works fine)
`http://mysite.mydomain.com/controltest/test.html?msg=123`

(complains)
`http://mysite.mydomain.com/controltest/test.aspx?msg=123`

I know the aspx version is being processed by the server before being sent to the client, but there aren’t any server-side commands or tags (it’s the same file, just copied and renamed).  As far as I can tell, the resulting page that is sent to the client is exactly the same.

Is there something about aspx vs html that would cause the control to not be able to get that variable?  I can see it fine from javascript that I add myself.

Here's the content of the page.  Not much to it.  If I get this working I intend to add some aspx tags and code, but there's no point yet.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    ActiveX Control Test
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <OBJECT ID="control1" CLASSID="..." CODEBASE="..." >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps, your control is parsing URL string manually and uses some regexp that expects only .html extension of the page. I would try to contact the control’s vendor regarding this problem or use iframe for ActiveX placement.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. I'm trying to get hold of them, but it's not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Eugene was correct, the third party control was doing a string search on the URL and was only looking for .html or .htm.